# Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand...after Dataadapter.update

Tags: mysql, vb.net, dataset, dataadapter

I have no problem with calling DataAdapter.update and adding 1 row to a MySQLdatabase.  I am having the Concurrency violation when I try to add another item and do an update.
I have a global DataAdapter and dataset declared.  I have this code run after I add a row to a table in the dataset.  First row added gets updated to the database with no issue but if I add another row and it calls the below function and errors with
Concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 after doing update again

```vb
Dim cmdBuilder As MySqlCommandBuilder
Using Connection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(Module1.ConnString)
    Try
        Connection.Open()
        cmdBuilder = New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
        cmdBuilder.GetInsertCommand()
        da.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = True
        da.Update(Table2Update, "Tabs3") 

       '  I even tried adding this code to refill the da with the updated table
       '  and still get the error
        'Table2Update.Tables(Table_Tabs).AcceptChanges()
        'Table2Update.Tables(Table_Tabs).Clear()
        'da.Fill(Table2Update.Tables(Table_Tabs))


        Connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.Print(Err.Description)
        Return Nothing
    Finally

    End Try
End Using
```

I am not super strong in DataAdapter so I apologize If I am missing something really simple.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The lines that call `GetInsertCommand` and set `AcceptChangesDuringUpdate` are pointless. The first is only useful if you actually make a change to the command you get and the second is the default anyway.

Comment: Is your database auto-generating IDs for that table? If so, after you do the first insert, take a look at what's in the database and what's in your `DataTable` to see whether they are the same. I suspect that they are not.

Comment: I will look at that but I did try da.Fill(Table2Update.Tables(Table_Tabs)) to refill the table with the updated info and still get the error.  regarding the 2 command lines thank you.  that is my lack of knowledge.

Comment: I check the table and there is no id to the row.  This is where my lack of knowledge is hindering me.  How do I get the table in the dataset to get the new id to populate in the table after doing DataAdapter update?  I did remove the 2 lines of code.

Comment: Some detail is missing here. When a dataadapter is given a datatable containing a row in the `DataRowState.Added` state, it will perform an `INSERT` to put that row to the db, then call `AcceptChanges()` on the row to mark it as `Unchanged`. That row will not participate in future operations unless something alters one of its properties, at which point it becomes `DataRowState.Modified` and will cause the dataadapter to attempt an `UPDATE`. I'll bet a dollar that, because your INSERT query did not do a "SELECT * FROM x WHERE id = last_insert_id` right after it did the insert, that the local..

Comment: ..ID column value is out of date (maybe it's -1, and the DB has calc'd 8723647 for the new row) so the UPDATE command has done `UPDATE x SET y = z WHERE id = @theWrongId` with -1 in the @wrongId parameter instead of 8723647. 0 rows are updated and you get a concurrency exception because the code assumes someone else changed the row too. What i'm puzzled by is your claim that no other changes have occurred to *this* row you just saved, the only thing you did was add another row and try and save it. This should mean your dt has 2 rows, one `Unchanged` and one `Added`, no UPDATE will be tried...

Comment: ...only an INSERT, which will also succeed, meaning that an error of "the updatecommand affected 0 rows" should not be encountered. Something is wonky with the problem description. Please provide a complete, minimal, verifiable reproduction of the code that leads to the error you're getting

Comment: I didn't realize I still needed to fill the dataset again with a call to the sql database.  I was thinking it automatically sent back and filled the new id for the row.  I added  Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(sql, Connection)
                cmd.CommandText = sql
                da.SelectCommand = cmd
                SalesTable.Clear()
                da.Fill(Main.KarmaDataSet, Table_Tabs)  and now my table is updated correctly.  That is the way it should be done.  Correct.  Thank you all for your help and insight.